# How to answer a question with a good answer?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

I'm new on Stack Overflow. I just want to ask how to make a good answer for answering any question? Is it sufficient to use good English structure?

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx

Comment: +1 for looking to improve the quality of answers you are providing!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it sufficient to use good English structure ?

Well, of course not.

The answer should be (at least):

- relevant to the question.
- actually answer the question.
- be correct.

Jon Skeet wrote about [how to answer questions on Stack Overflow](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) a while ago. Good tips.

Answer (score -3):

As long as your answer is factual, useful and accurate, it's good.  Don't worry about spelling and grammar so much, there are plenty of people here who scan each question as soon as it's submitted and edit it for a quick 2 points (unless they've hit the daily limit).  That's not to say you should intentionally mess up your English, but just don't be concerned if it's not your strongpoint.

Comment: I disagree that you shouldn't worry about spelling and grammar "so much".  You should try your best and someone will edit to be helpful if you make a mistake.  But I don't want to downplay the fact that you shouldn't at least make a good attempt.

Comment: There is no daily limit to edits.  Also note that the vast majority of edits on the site are from 2k+ users, not those suggesting edits.  Finally, ensuring that an answer is clear, understandable, and won't be mis-understood is *very* important.  While some mistakes are okay, it's quite important to spend a fair bit of time ensuring that your writing is as good as you can make it (especially if you know you're not as comfortable with that language).  If you don't take that time odds are it won't be *possible* to fix the post in edits.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Re-read the last sentence.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I saw that, but there is a huge difference between intentionally messing up the grammar and not trying to make a good attempt.  You are suggesting a user not worry about grammar as much as they should.  Servy's point is exactly right.  They need to take the effort to make it clear and understandable and not subject to misinterpretation.